# How can I / can I at all, search questions from mobile (iPhone)?

Tags: feature-request, search, mobile-web, mobile-safari

In preparation for a job interview, and with my computer in the shop for repairs, I pulled up SO to search for Python / Django questions, only to be unable to find search in the top-of-window search. Could there fat least be a findable option to opt-in to search capabilities being easily available from the mobile interface? I know that preferred best practice is to simplify / streamline mobile features, but search is powerful, basic, and useful.

P.S. Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I know it's polite at least to search the forums to see if the question has been asked... but... um... uh...

Answer (score 5):

In the upper right corner of the mobile page is a button (with a little triangle on it) that shows additional option when you click on it. Among other things there is a search box.

Entering search words and starting the search with <kbd>Enter</kbd> brings you to the search results.